# PUBG like matching feature

Tags: pubg

I want to create the website where I want the PUBG feature like matching the online gamers and set the game between them, so I just wanted to know how I can do that whoever users are online on my website I want to make a matching between them and set the quiz game between them?

Comment: Your question is way too broad to be answered, but given there are other websites for this, I would presume there is some publicly available API you can use to communicate with said PUBG servers.

Comment: Quick google search returned this on the official website: https://documentation.pubg.com/en/introduction.html

Comment: To know a user's online status in real-time you can use socket.io.

Comment: @ericlong is it possible to know a user's status through socket io and then using webRTC displaying them the same things, in my case, it is the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Match making is a very heavy feature to make on your own so if you use cloud services for game hosting, they provide match-making features. i.e.

AWS Gamelift provides different types for player [match-making](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamelift/latest/flexmatchguide/match-create-configuration.html).

These services are way more optimized than making manually. So I suggest better use them to add match making feature.

Comment: I'm thinking, initially, I will match some limited demo players by randomly selecting their user IDs. Later on, if I get a good number of visitors in my website then i will switch to cloud services.